# Has Stack Exchange ever considered offering a scholarship?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, donation

Has Stack Exchange Inc. ever considered the possibility of offering a scholarship to help college students?

I think this would be a great way to encourage and support those going into the software development field.

<sub>Disclamer: I am a high school senior interested in finding scholarship money.</sub>

Comment: Nice disclaimer :)

Comment: Is this "Whoever has the most rep at the end of the school year gets the money?"

Comment: Whoever has the most rep at the end of the school year is not guaranteed to have the best marks... probably spent too much time getting rep :-).

Comment: Judging by the votes for this question, there might be 15 others who are also interested in a scholarship.

Comment: On an unrelated note, Jon Skeet is going back to school to get another degree.  --- Good luck getting that scholarship now.

Comment: @ben: [No kidding.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended/5455770#comment6198282_5455770)

Comment: Also, do universities accept Unicorn Dollars?  I'm quite confident SO can get you lots of those, no problem.

Comment: I believe we have a moderator that's quickly approaching college age...

Comment: @psubsee2003 I was considering adding to the post that it may be best to not have SE activity be the only factor considered, as it could encourage voting fraud. (Yes, I know there are measures in place to prevent this, but I'd rather not test them by putting actual money at stake.)

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately, I don't know of any college that accepts Unicorn Dollars, but maybe someone could create a website where unicorn dollars can be exchanged for USD. Does anyone know the going Unicorn->USD exchange rate? Google's currency converter doesn't seem to support Unicorn Dollars: https://www.google.com/finance/converter

Comment: @JoshuaDwire The current rate is 3.1415926 : 0

Comment: They never paid for me to go party for four years, why should they pay you?

Comment: Weren't the dreams and souls you crashed as a moderator payment enough @Won't?

Comment: @Yannis You can't put crushed souls and dreams on the dinner table, y'know?

Comment: @Yannis: What good is crushing hopes and dreams if you can't brag about it over a keg with your bros ?

Comment: Would this be U.S. Only? If so, would that be fair? If not, how would it work?

Comment: @perhapsPekka If implemented, it would be neat if it could be offered outside of the U.S., but many U.S. companies only offer scholarships to students attending accredited U.S. colleges. (I have seen a few exceptions, but I can't find them right now.)

Comment: It'd be cheaper to offer outside the US... and now a significant amount of SE's staff is European (especially though also elsewhere) it's not like it's unprecedented doing something in other countries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, no. I can't say for sure if it's something we would think about at some point, though I personally don't think we'd be any more likely to set up a scholarship than any other tech startup.

That said, if I were considering it, I'd at least think that limiting things to software development would be a bit odd. We have over 100 sites, many of which don't have anything to do with software development while still being quite valuable.

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/988/introducing-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program) a related issue?

Comment: @AndreSilva Oh hey, I forgot about that. That project was before my time. I'm not sure what all happened with it then, but we aren't working on any similar initiatives at the moment.

Comment: +1 for not limiting it to software development, if we ever get around to considering it.

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like a great idea. I would be fearful of it being based off of reputation directly, but I would encourage it to be something akin to applying for a job in Careers 2.0. Link a sampling of good questions, other relevant experience, etc. It could be done initially for Stack Overflow, and expended to the entire site if possible.

Furthermore, I think it would be more interesting if people were allowed to either donate to a general scholarship fund, or perhaps sponsor enough money to look at the applications and award scholarships, much as the Careers 2.0 site works.

In fact, why not just call it Scholarships 2.0?

Comment: Yea, I like the sponsor idea. I have a feeling companies like Microsoft would donate?

Comment: How about calling it Pre-Careers 2.0? And, give Careers profiles to the top *x* candidates?

Comment: for every n reputation donated to the scholarship fund, stack exchange puts up $1